# How to price zero coupon bonds with short term rates model?

Tags: fixed-income, bond, short-rate

I want to find the price of Zero coupon bond given a short rate model.

I think about Merton, Vasiceck, CIR, Ho & Lee models.

1) Given a simulation of $r_t$ how can I calculate $ P(t,T) = \mathbb{E}^Q\left[\left. \exp{\left(-\int_t^T r_s\, ds\right) } \right| \mathcal{F}_t \right] $ ?

Using the simulations i think it would be easy to calculate the integral. But how to calculate the integral knowing $\mathcal{F}_t$ ? Am I supposed to find an expression of $r_s$ depending on $r_t$ ?

2) How to deal with the risk neutral probability here ?

3) Would this approach still be ok with a time dependant model ? (Hull White) 
Would this approach still be good with multiple factor model ? (Logstaff Schwartz)

Comment: All good questions but i think youll find all the answers you need in a good fixed income book e.g brigo&mercurio

Comment: I believe so for closed formulae. But i can't find anything about how to deal with the formula above in practice, how to deal with Q and Ft.

Comment: Regarding 2) All models depend on a set of parameters that you calibrate to observed market prices, once that is done you are using risk neutral probabilities.

Comment: The solution http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/15956/ho-and-lee-derivation-for-short-rates-model may partially answered your question

Comment: Here's the solution for the Vasicek model:
https://quant.stackexchange.com/q/47522/26559

Answer (score 3):

If you do not know anything about the dynamics of you short-rate $r_t$, then there is no way to express the price of the zero coupon bond better than what your already have:

$ P(t,T) = \mathbb{E}^Q\left[\left. \exp{\left(-\int_t^T r_s\, ds\right) } \right| \mathcal{F}_t \right] $

You can use a model given in this [page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-rate_model) where you should be able to find close formulas for the zero coupon bond, if available, in their respective wiki pages or in FI books.

Comment: I'd like to understand how to work with this formula given a short rate dynamic. (ie. how to find the closed formula when it is possible and how to use a simulated path of $r_t$ to calculate it when it is not possible.)

Comment: Regarding how to arrive at a closed form solution this answer is quite good: [Use of Girsanov's theorem in bond pricing](http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/10763/use-of-girsanovs-theorem-in-bond-pricing)